# LaTeX can not find pdfTeX

Tags: installing, texworks

After updating system operation my LaTeX file gave me this error

```
 You need a TeX distribution like MacTeX installed on your system to
 typeset your document. When a TeX distribution is installed you may
 need to tell TeXworks where to find it in Edit -> Preferences ->
 Typesetting.
```

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not LaTeX that can not find pdftex.  But it is TeXworks.  What kind of system do you have, and what kind of upgrade did you do?

Comment: did you update to El Capitan?

Comment: system operation OS X . that is right it is Texworks

Comment: yes I did update  El Capitan

Comment: I already installed MacTeX but still not working

Comment: does any body knows please?

Comment: MacTeX 2015, or something earlier? [TeX on El Capitan](https://tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html) at TUG indicates 2015 should work fine, but I'd guess 2014 and earlier won't.

Comment: it is MacTex 2015 but it is not work fine

Comment: Can you start TeX from the command line? Use `tex --version` to find this out.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: does any body knows?

Comment: @Mesh --- TeXworks is just a front end. The `TeX` engine and related tools are also available from the terminal. Open Terminal from Applications -> Utilities and enter `tex --version`.

Comment: @Mesh, you should use @-pinging to notify other users of your replies. Otherwise, we'll never know you responded. Ian gives the right information though; what does `tex --version` give you?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of TexWorks mistake. When you go to TexWorks-> Preferences-> Typesetting and change the path for tex and related programs and processing tools and set OK. The change is not accepted by TexWorks. I also wanted to change for Context I could not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

`TeXworks` -> `Preferences` -> `Typesetting`

Click the `+` button for the first box and Choose the path of `texbin` which  contain many file including `pdflatex`.

In my case this the path:

```
/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin
```

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Mac Os Sierra and had exactly the same problem. I went to TeXworks -> Preferences -> Typesetting and clicked Restore Defaults. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

`TeXworks` -> `Preferences` -> `Typesetting`

Click the `+` button for the first box `Paths for TeX and related programs.` and choose the following folder:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I restored everything to defaults in Format>>Preferences>>Typesetting and then restarted the program. Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a folder which contains a lot of `exe` files. you could find it by a simple search in your Linux driver for example search `xelatex` or `bibtex` or `bibtexu` . after finding the folder which contains these `exe` files, add it in 
`Preferences` >> `Typesetting` (press [+] button in path for `tex` and related programs section, not in processing tools section, then bring it to the first row)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a possible solution:

On your console:

```
set PDFLATEX=C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex

set MAKEINDEX=C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex
```

This definition of environmental variables explicitly gives access to two of the executables necessary for generating a PDF for documentation.